# How can I get cookies from a request to a webservice using Play Framework 2.0?

Tags: web-services, authentication, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I get cookies from a authentication request to a webservice that uses session?
I can not change the webservice implementation.

```
public static Result authenticate(){
    Form<Login> f = form(Login.class).bind(request().body().asJson());

    Promise<WS.Response> result = WS.url("http://site/login")
        .post("{\"login\":\"login\", \"password\":\"password\"}");

    return async(result.map(
            new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WS.Response response) throws Throwable {
                    if(response.getStatus() == OK){
                        JsonNode jn = response.asJson();
                        session("username", jn.get("login").toString());

                        // how can I get cookies from webservice?

                        return ok(jn);
                    }else{
                        return internalServerError();
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684103/how-can-i-put-a-cookie-in-jersey-restful-webservice#answer-9706362). The first webservice response has Set-Cookie header.

```
response.getHeader("Set-Cookie");
```