# Jersey adding cookie to subsequent requests

Tags: java, cookies, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to implement an authenticate mechanism with a jersey 2.13 client. But I'm not able to get the responded cookie with a session-id set to the client and that subsequent client requests automatically request including the session cookie.

My idea was to solve this with ClientResponseFilter and ClientRequestFilter.

```
   public class AuthResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext, ClientResponseContext clientResponseContext) throws IOException {

            Map<String, NewCookie> cookies = clientResponseContext.getCookies();
        }
    }
```

The clientResponseContextParameter has the session-cookie set. But i'm not sure how it'll be possible to automatically set that cookie to subsequent client requests.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713893/jersey-client-adding-cookies-to-request?rq=1