# java ssl multiple client certificates

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, x509, jersey-1.0

I have a server that is configured to accept any client certificate signed by a private CA, but can't seem to get multiple clients to connect to it with different private keys for testing.

I am attempting to create a unit test that connects with admin to set the test up, then disconnects, reconnects as limited-user does stuff before disconnecting, and then opening with admin again to verify the limited-user operation was successful.

Connecting with just one client works perfectly fine, the issue is that my server logs show that admin logs in all 3 times, because as wireshark confirms, the ssl sessions are just using abbreviated session-resumption handshakes instead of renegotiating each connection.

Is there a way to force the jersey client to renegotiate each connection?

Client test code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "admin.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
makeClient().resource(getResetURI()).post(Response.class, RESET_DATA);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "limited-user.jks");
makeClient().resource(getUpdateURI()).post(Response.class, TEST_UPDATE_SMALL_DATA); // this connection is actually as admin

...
    public Client makeClient() {
        final DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getProperties().put(ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_HANDLE_COOKIES, true);    
        clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
        String keystore = Util.getSystemProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");;
        String keystorePassword = Util.getSystemProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
        try{
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            try(FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(keystore)){
                ks.load(fis, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            }
            kmf.init(ks, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sslctx.getClientSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1);
            sslctx.getClientSessionContext().setSessionTimeout(1);
            // TODO: the below two nulls are probably insecure
            sslctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
            clientConfig.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(null, sslctx));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        /* we must construct our own handler in order to override the Retry handler */
        final ApacheHttpClientHandler clientHandler = new ApacheHttpClientHandler(new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager()), clientConfig);
        clientHandler.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(0, false));

    Client tclient = new ApacheHttpClient(clientHandler);
    tclient.setFollowRedirects(true);
    return tclient;
}
```

I've also tried resetting the ssl sessions between calls, but this doesn't have any effect as far as I can see:

```
SSLSessionContext ssc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2").getClientSessionContext();
for (Enumeration<byte[]> e = ssc.getIds(); e.hasMoreElements();)
{
   byte[] id = e.nextElement();
   ssc.getSession(id).invalidate();
   System.out.println("Invalidating!");
}
Thread.sleep(1100);
```

Is it possible to change the certificates in just one JVM or must I spawn multiple JVMs for this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache HTTP Client does not support using multiple certs in a single JVM. The original Jersey client does support per-instance certs, though, and switching to it should enable the per-instance configuration. Do note that the Apache HTTP Client is often used for it's cookie management, so if you need that, you will have to reimplement cookie management on the Jersey client (see [Jersey Client: Adding Cookies to Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713893/jersey-client-adding-cookies-to-request) for a simple implementation)