# how can i get 'jsessionid' using jersey client?

Tags: java, jersey-client

I'm using jersey-client 1.19.4 to test my web application.
If I test with postman, I can find the cookie "JSESSIONID" after 'send' action. And I can find 'jsessionid=...' in ClientResponse.toString(), But ClientResponse.getCookies() returns nothing.

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(someUrl);
FormDataMultiPart   formData = new FormDataMultiPart();
formData.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("userId", userId));
formData.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("uPasswd", uPasswd));
ClientResponse  response = webResource.accept("*/*").type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
System.out.println("response: " + response.toString());  // 'jsessionid' found here
List<NewCookie> cookies = response.getCookies();
System.out.println("# of cookies: " + cookies.size());  // prints "# of cookies: 0"
```

How can I get "JSESSIONID" from ClientResponse?

Comment: Have you checked the response headers? Like so: `(( MultivaluedMap<String,String>)response.getHeaders()).get("JSESSIONID")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSESSIONID` can be set in few different ways. As per  
[JSR-000315 Java Servlet 3.0 Final Release](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), chapter 7.1 Session Tracking Mechanisms, following can be used:

> - Cookies
> - SSL Sessions
> - URL Rewriting

In your case it appears that URL Rewriting is being used. The two most common reasons being:

- The server is configured not to issue cookies
- Your client doesn't support cookies

Since you get the cookie while using Postman it most likely means that your Jersey Client doesn't handle cookies. One way to integrate it with Apache HttpClient using `jersey-apache-client` [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403800/1602555).

Answer (score 1):

From the mailing list:

http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Session-Handling-not-working-with-Jersey-Client-td4519663.html

> The Jersey client by default uses HttpURLConnection that does not
>   support cookie management (and thus sessions).
>
> You need to switch to using the [Apache HTTP client](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-apache-client/1.11/com/sun/jersey/client/apache/package-summary.html) support.
>
> Then set the following property to true: [PROPERTY_HANDLE_COOKIES](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-apache-client/1.17.1/com/sun/jersey/client/apache/config/ApacheHttpClientConfig.html#PROPERTY_HANDLE_COOKIES)
>
> ```
> DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig config = new  
> DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig(); config
>     .setProperty("com.sun.jersey.impl.client.httpclient.handleCookies",  
>         true);
> ApacheHttpClient c = ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
> ```
>
> Plus you can also use authorization with the Apache HTTP client
>   integration.
>
> ```
>   DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig config = new   DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
>   config.getState().setCredentials(null, null, -1, "foo", "bar");
>   ApacheHttpClient c = ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
>   WebResource r = c.resource("http://host/base");
>   String s = r.get(String.class);
>   s = r.post(String.class, s);
> ```